# Why we cannot use TIMESTAMP datatype for fields created & modified in cakephp2.x?

Tags: php, cakephp, phpmyadmin

As we know MYSQL datetime datatype taking more memory that TIMESTAMP. For rapid development I am using cakephp2.x. **My concern is why we are not using TIMESTAMP for created and modified field in database.?** I  read cakephp2.x  document, they not mention the reason in technical terms clearly. Expect good answer from expert!

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main difference is that DATETIME is constant while TIMESTAMP is affected by the time_zone setting.

Also, the space needed for both can be seen as pretty much identical if you don't have billions of rows (4 bytes Vs 8 bytes, but still nothing really). the datetime fields can also be used for easy comparison and calculation.

My recommendation: So just stick to datetime and don't create an issue where there is none really.
There are usually way more troubling issues at hand when starting to develop an application.

Answer (score -1):

To me it proved itself multiple times that one should avoid using the created and updated automatic fields of CakePHP, or at most for forensical bookkeeping (i.e. you should never use its values in your app).

It is unflexible, lacks customization like internationalization, could work more efficient.

Whenever I need to store a time, I do in in an INT field as a Unix timestamp. This also works well with multiple timezones and different environments (e.g. TZ in DB vs PHP).